# Run time error 91 in VBA macro to hit search button in website Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This little script is supposed to go to the website
http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Default.jsp

Insert under the tab "Search" inside the `"Symbol/Cusip"` box the number `111320AE7` and click on the `"Show Results"` button to get the results.

```
Sub SearchSite()
    Dim beta
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Default.jsp"

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    objIE.document.getElementById("firscreener-cusip").Value = "111320AE7"

    Set beta = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("ms-finra-advanced-search-btn")(1)

    beta.Click

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    'objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

I get Run-time error `91: Object variable or With block variable not set`

The problem appears to be the `beta.click` line

I would appreciate some help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line and debug your code, then I think you'll find that `beta` is nothing. The problem will be with the previous line that sets `beta`. Fix that and you'll be okay,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beta is referencing the div that contains the buttons.  The element arrays are base 0.  They start at 0 not 1.

```
Sub SearchSite()
    Dim beta, buttons, btnReset, btnSubmit
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Default.jsp"

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4

    Loop

    objIE.document.getElementById("firscreener-cusip").Value = "111320AE7"

    Set beta = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("ms-finra-advanced-search-btn")(0)

'   <div class="ms-finra-advanced-search-btn">
'       <input class="button_blue" value="CLEAR CRITERIA" type="reset">
'       <input class="button_blue" value="SHOW RESULTS" type="submit">
'    </div>

    Set buttons = beta.GetElementsByTagName("input")

    WScript.Echo buttons(0).outerHTML

'   <input class="button_blue" value="CLEAR CRITERIA" type="reset">

    Set btnReset = buttons(0)

'    <input class="button_blue" value="SHOW RESULTS" type="submit">

    Set btnSubmit = buttons(0)


    beta.btnSubmit

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4

    Loop
    objIE.Quit

End Sub
```